# Finding Query window in ALM

Tags: sql-server-2014, hp-alm

I am trying to use some SQL queries in HP-ALM, but I am unable to find the query window. 
In HP website, it says 
1.On the ALM sidebar, under Dashboard, select Analysis View.

2.Expand the analysis tree and select an Excel report.

3.Under the Configuration tab, click the Query tab, and then click the Query Builder button.

I am unable to find what is stated in STEP 2, Does any one have idea on this? Also, I am trying to find the path of a Test suite, How would I do it using SQL in ALM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Step 1:** Choose "Analysis View" under the Dashboard:

[image]

**Step 2:** Click the Excel Reports folder under the analysis view. **Note** that if you cannot see this tree or window, this means you were not given permissions to the Analysis modoule and you should contact your ALM Administrator.

[image]

**Step 3:** Here you can write your SQL query and generate it into an Excel sheet:

[image]

Comment: Thank You @Koby for the answer, it helps. Also, Do you know the proper way to include path while exporting test cases from Excel to ALM

Comment: @Avi - Happy to help. Voting up on my answer would also be appreciated. Regarding your 2nd question - I don't completely understand. Could you open a new question and post the link here in the comments so I can help you further?